# Programmatically checking for a device of a specific type in Linux

Tags: python, linux, embedded-linux

I'm writing a segment in my python program (on Linux) that allows a user to record a short audio file. Of course, the first step in the code is to check whether a mic is present. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to do so reliably.

I want it to work independent of:

1. The model of USB mic
2. The order in which it and any other audio devices were plugged-in/enumerated
3. Whether the device was hot or cold plugged

Is this possible? I've considered:

- udev rules and the 'udevadm info' command (conflicts with items 1 & 3 above)
- aplay/arecord (specifying the device with the --device option conflicts with item 2)
- lsusb command (conflicts with 1)
- Checking for specific a device node or file in the /dev and /sys directories (conflicts with 1 & 2)

This is pushing the limits of my linux knowledge so there's a decent chance that I've made some incorrect assumptions about the potential conflicts above.

Answer (score 0):

> Of course, the first step in the code is to check whether a mic is present.

This is trickier than you think. Using the [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) package it's relatively easy to discover available input devices...

```
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
  dev = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
  if dev.get('maxInputChannels', 0) > 0:
    print('Input device: ', dev.get('name'))
```

...but on my system, there are at least four different input devices...one is a conference mic, one is the mic input from my headset, one is the mic on my camera, and one is the mic on a USB sound device that I only use to drive a set of speakers. There's no way to programatically decide which of those I actually want to use.

---

If you assume a simple setup (e.g., only a single microphone), you can just ask PyAudio to record and it will use the default input device. See the example in the PyAudio docs for more details:

```
stream = p.open(input=True, ...)
```

This seems to meet your requirements. If no input devices are available, this will fail:

```
>>> s = p.open(input=True, rate=44100, channels=2, format=pyaudio.paInt16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)
```